# IPhone connect issue on VmWare (Ubuntu Host, MacOS Guest)

Tags: usb, vmware, iphone

I need to have macos as a guest OS on vmware workstation player and it installed and everything works great except my iphone that the guest cannot recognize it correctly, according to following image the OS has identified it on USB2 but iTunes doesn't recognize it as iphone device connected!

as a matter of fact there is no issue if I use windows as host instead of Ubuntu but I prefer Ubuntu over Windows and am looking for a solution.

[image: macos identify the device]

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I finally worked out,
Here is a solution:

[opem vmware edit vid: pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139020/macos-on-vmware-doesnt-recognize-ios-device)

usb.quirks.device0 = "0xvid:0xpid skip-reset, skip-refresh, skip-setconfig"

1. [disable SIP](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abelardojarab/0fc2f0af699ad1b42b1ec7937e7b2ee4/raw/9eb33d05a30e5df3d01a947540918ba8eefd813e/disable_sip_vmware.md)
2. [install mac ports](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
3. sudo launchctl unload
   /Library/Apple/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.usbmuxd.plist
4. sudo port install usbmuxd
5. sudo usbmuxd --foreground
6. then connect iPhone and let the guest to take control

**Disabling SIP**

1. Start vmware
2. select guest and "power to firmware"
3. in efi menu, enter setup > config boot options > add boot options > select recovery partition > select boot.efi
4. at input file description hit  and type in label e.g. "recovery" > commit changes and exit
5. boot from recovery and be patient
6. follow prompt until you see OS X Utilities menu
7. At the very top menu select Utilities > Terminal
8. In terminal enter "csrutil status"
9. then csrutil disable
10. then csrutil status
11. then reboot > hit enter once or twice
12. Double check in OSX Terminal app to ensure SIP is disabled

Finally, disable HiDPI:

$  sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool NO

[Referenced from:](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/497)